# Is it possible to make a text inside horizontal line like i'm doing?

Tags: html, css

I don't get it what i doing wrong here. **I want the small text to look a like the big one** without fixed values (run the snipped to see)

Have some way to do this that don't involves text being surrounded by two pseudo-elements?

```css
.ruler {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
height: 0px;
}

.text1 {
background-color: white;
padding: 0px 2px;
transform: translateY(-50%);
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 12px;
}

.text2 {
background-color: white;
padding: 0px 2px;
transform: translateY(-50%);
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ruler">
<span class="text1">MyText</span>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="ruler">
<span class="text2">MyText</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you say why pseudo elements are ruled out? My worry is that you are putting what are essentially just visual clues, the lines, into the actual DOM as if they have some content-meaning which they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious to what you mean by `I want the small text to look a like the big one without fixed values (run the snipped to see)` I have an example of making them the same. Can you please provide some clarification below if this is not what you are looking for? Possibly a screenshot example of what you are looking for in your original question may be the most helpful.

```css
.ruler {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
height: 0px;
}

.text {
background-color: white;
padding: 0px 2px;
transform: translateY(-50%);
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ruler">
  <span class="text">MyText</span>
</div>

<br />

<div class="ruler">
  <span class="text">MyText</span>
</div>
```

Comment: is because the small text was not centralized like the big was, i thought that everyone would get it with the snipped clearly showing the difference, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all the confusion, I eventually solved the problem by going the other way around.

I would delete this question and add this answer to a related question, but I can do neither.

Whatever... here's the answer:

```css
.ruler {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
}

.text1 {
background-color: white;
padding: 0px 2px;
transform: translateY(50%);
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 12px;
padding-top: 2px;
}

.text2 {
background-color: white;
padding: 0px 2px;
transform: translateY(50%);
display: inline-block;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 16px;
padding-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ruler">
<span class="text1">MyText</span>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="ruler">
<span class="text2">MyText</span>
</div>
```

The `padding-top: 2px` acts the same with all text sizes, because it's there to compensate the border size.

Comment: The lines are not centralised vertically on the complete character height. Your answer may well be giving you what you wanted in the first place, but it would be helpful if you could make exactly clear what you wanted in your question (the centralisation is taking no note of descenders).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> ::after or ::before

```css
.title {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;

}
.title::before {
     content: '';
     z-index: -1;
     width: 100%;
     height: 2px;
     background: #000;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


span.text2 {
     font-size: 18px;
     background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <span class="text2">MyText</span>
</div>
```

I used :

> :before

it's relative to the div that has the span, I center it with top, left, and transform properties will make it however the size of the span, it will be always in the center

---

Note: that it's a line passing through the whole div, so I gave the span background so it will cover it, and give you the possibility to control the padding from the text and line

---

hope it's useful